# Pragmatically quartz in grails

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have a problem. I wanna create a Job but not when application is started.
I wanna invoke method from pingServcie but is null.

This is my code:

Job class

```
class MyJob implements Job {

def pingService

 @Override
    void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
      pingService.checkPing()
   }
}
```

I read somewhere that I need bean with my Service class, because Spring Autowire  doesn't work in this case, so I create it (I never work with bean so I don't if this is correct).
I create `resources.xml` instead of `resources.groovy`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <bean name="pingService" class="inzynierka.PingService" />
</beans>
```

But this doesn't work.

Finally, I did something like this.

```
class MyJob implements Job {

def PingService pingService

 @Override
    void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
      JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
      pingService = dataMap.getWrappedMap().get("pingService")
      pingService.checkPing()
   }
}
```

I passing params in different class like this

```
job.getJobDataMap().put("pingService", pingService)
```

and it works.

Comment: it doesn't appear that your using the service correctly.  You don't have to create a bean in the resources file because grails will do this for you.  Do you actually have a PingService.groovy in the grails services package?

Comment: Any reason that you are not using the quartz plugin?